# isalpha : If argv is not alphabets. How to conditionise?

Tags: c++, c

I have made a program which accepts 2 command line arguments in which the first argument is the file name itself, and second a alphabetical keyword. If I have to reject any numeric argument how do I conditionise, or what do I write?

My pseudocode:

> If argv[1] is not alphabets then reject it(return 1).

How do I do this? Sorry I'm a newbie to computer programming and C in particular.

***EDIT:*** The second argument is a string. I have to check that the user enters a string and no numberic value. If the user inputs a number, or a string with number( like bacon11 ), My program should reject it and return 1; What should I do?

My code looks like this:

```
 // Reject numeric value
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
{
    if //TODO: if letter is not a letter reject it.
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What should I write in the TODO line? I cant conditionise the code!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The best course of action is to go through a good book on C or C++ (you will need to decide which of the two you are learning, they are different languages) and learn the basics. For C, I recommend "The C Programming Language", a very accessible book written by the authors of the language.

Comment: Please note: `argv[1]` is the first argument, and `argv[2]` is the second one; maybe you need to check `argv[2]`?

Comment: @anatolyg: THe computer starts indexing from 0. Dosent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) function.

**EDIT**: Your code seems to be in good way. Nevertheless, I will not do your work, but I can give you some clues!

- Check [this tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) to understand the if statement (you could also check the [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) example).
- Don't forget that argv is a 2 dimensional character array. So to get a specific character of an argument you can do: `argv[i][j]`
- Check the **return value** of the [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) function to test a character.

Comment: An example would be nice, since `isalpha` expects an `int`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Did you look at the link? It has an example there.

Comment: @PomfCaster The example is, of course, incorrect, and will lead to undefined behavior if the text is not a constant.

Comment: Some edits for the question: The second argument is a string. I have to check that the user enters a string and no numberic value. If the user inputs a number, or a string with number( like bacon11 ), My program should reject it and return 1; What should I do? 

My code looks like this:
   
     // Reject numeric value
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        if //TODO: if letter is not a letter reject it.
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

What should I write in the TODO line? I cant conditionise the code!

Answer (score 1):

In the most general sense, this could be a thorny problem, since
the definition of "alphabetic" may be locale dependent, and will
depend on the encoding used by the environment; if the encoding
is UTF-8 (a common case today), it can be very difficult, since
you have to deal with multibyte characters.

On the other hand, you state that the second argument is an
alphabetical keyword.  If there are a fixed number of keywords
(and they wouldn't be keywords otherwise), the simplest solution
is just to look up the argument in a table of keywords; if you
don't find it, it's an error.  Something like:

```
static std::string keywords[] =
{
    "keyword1",
    "keyword2",
    //  ...
};

if ( std::find( std::begin( keywords ), std::end( keywords ), argv[2] )
        == std::end( keywords ) ) {
    //  Error, keyword not found.
}
```

Or, if by "alphabetic", you mean one of the 26 characters in the
English alphabet (and can exclude accented characters, or
Cyrillic, or Chinese, or anything like that), which is often the
case when one is only concerned with keywords, then you can
check whether each character is alphabetic, using the `isalpha`
function (correctly, of course):

```
if ( std::find_if( argv[2], argv[2] + strlen( argv[2] ),
            []( unsigned char ch ) { return !isalpha( ch ); } )
        != argv[2] + strlen( argv[2] ) ) {
    //  Error, non alphabetic found...
}
```

As written, this only works in C++11; with older versions of
C++, it's more complicated.  And it's very limited; usually, the
first thing an experienced C++ programmer does is set the global
locale to that of his user, which likely isn't "C".